# Flask-Restful 404 when api is started in __init__.py

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am using Twilio's `flask.ext.restful` extension with the following setup:

Top level folder is `app`

Inside of which is: `___init___.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext import restful

# Basic app configuration
app = Flask(__name__)
api = restful.Api(app)
```

and inside this `app module` a file called `api.py`

```
from flask.ext.restful import Resource
from app import api

class HelloWorld(restful.Resource):
    def get(self):
         return {'hello': 'world'}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/hello')
```

This setup just gives me 404s when accessing `/hello`

However, if I move the `api.py` to the `__init__.py` model then everything works.

Why is this the case?

Comment: How do you import `api.py`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the app gets ran before api.py gets executed and it hangs on Flask. How are you executing this?

```
class HelloWorld(restful.Resource)
```

should be

```
class HelloWorld(Resource)
```

however

Answer (score 0):

Try transferring `from app import api` to your `__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext import restful

# Basic app configuration
app = Flask(__name__)
api = restful.Api(app)

from app import api
```

Also, you should rename one of the `app` to avoid confusion.